# Как обьедиенить интернет с нескольких устройств андроид в один канал

Tags: android, linux, сеть

Задача такая. есть 10 устройств андроид с подключением LTE скорость 10Мб/с. ТО есть общая скорость подключения 100Мб\с как собрать всю скорость в один канал, то есть подключить хост ко всем 10 устройствам. хотелось бы уточнить технические возможности увеличения количества андроид устройст до 100 или даже более штук. Какие есть существующие програмные решения для этой задачи, может какая то прошивка есть специальная или что то подобное
.

Comment: https://mikrotik.me/blog-MultiWAN.html

Comment: Напишите свои полные ожидания (цели) от такой настройки

Comment: Andrey Mihalev расширить канал связи на конечном хосте, и возможно даже распределеление совокупной скорости по сети между другими хостами

Comment: don Rumata интересная статья. Сейчас изучу внимательно

Comment: хочу  развесить 10 сматфонов в режиме модема 24\7 и подключиться ко всем с одного хоста и пользоваться широченным каналом связи без необходимости тянуть оптоволокно.

Comment: а модем с агрегацией не дешевле купить?

Comment: eri этот что за зверь? если я правильно понимаю ты хочешь сказать есть модем куда можно вставить 10 сим карт и он обьединит трафик с них в общий шлз ?

Comment: @eri как я понял агрегация каналов позволяет увеличить пропускную способность одной сим карты в несколько раз, но это не отменяет для решения моей задачи необходимости обьединить максимально возможную скорость доступа к сети с одной симки в один широкий канал с совокупной скорстью,  если знаешь как мне ускорить процесс подскажи

Comment: Тут возможны 2 задачи. Первая это получить всю скорость в одном соединении. Вторая это раскидать соединения по разным каналам. Вам какой вариант нужен?